# Photoshop Panels with javascript

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I wonder if it is possible, to create custom panel in Photoshop using just javascript? And eventually add as extension to photoshop or something that kind?

Also is it possible to extend existing panel i.e. add another "checkbox" similar to eye that shows/hides layers just somewhere near current eye checkbox?

Comment: No, this wouldn't be possible using javascript. I think that C++ is what is used for creating photoshop plug-ins.

Comment: @Billy uhhh yes you can. You can use scriptUI which comes packaged with photoshops js engine

Comment: @pdizz - Uhhh my bad then I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scriptUI library included with Photoshop. [This is the best reference ive ever found on the topic.](http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/scriptui.html) I don't think you can extend existing panels.

Comment: Thanks, It should work perfectly for me. Still if somebody would find a way to extend existing panel, I'll be glad.